# Is a day trip from Naha City to Taketomi Island possible?

Tags: japan, okinawa

I will be staying in a guest house in Naha City, the capital of Okinawa prefecture in Japan, and was considering a day trip to [Taketomi Island](https://wikitravel.org/wiki/en/index.php?title=Taketomi&printable=yes)

Taketomi is one of the so-called "Isolated Island" of the Japanese Yaeyama islands. So far, I got that the main way to go there is:

1. go to Ishigaki Island by plane (50 min)
2. travel to the ferry terminal (40 min)
3. take a 10-min ferry to Taketomi.

Including waiting time, I guess it takes 2h30 at most. This seems realistic. But all day trip tours I can find starts from Ishigaki, so I am starting to think that the trip is not that easy to do in one day.

My questions:

1. Is it possible to do a one day trip to Taketomi Island from Naha City? Waking up really early/going back really late is not an issue.
2. If so, are there guided tour departing from Naha City?
3. If I travel alone, is it fine to buy the ferry and/or plane tickets on the spot? As I am not sure at what time I would finish my day trip, I am not sure how to make a reservation.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible, as you have figured out yourself. Buying ferry tickets on the spot is no problem; buying plane tickets on the spot is possible too but is expensive (about 20,000 yen, versus about 5,000 if bought sufficiently in advance) and there is a risk that the flight will be booked out already.